# Please help me with Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I'm trying to deal with `Spring MVC`. I made a simple example

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class HelloController {
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String printWelcome(ModelMap model) {
        model.addAttribute("message", "Hello world!");
        model.addAttribute("name", "Pavel!");
        return "hello";
    }
}
```

and

```
<html>
<body>
    <h1>${message}</h1>
    <h1>${name}</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

and all the cool running.
but then I wanted to add a method

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String printUser(User user) {
    user.setName("Pavel");
    user.setSname("Petrashov");
    user.setAge(24);
    return "user";
}
```

and now I do not know how to get the data in `user.jsp`

I have just two hours ago, began to study and still poorly guided. please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Model Map](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/ui/ModelMap.html) is there to help you out

```
 @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String printUser(User user,ModelMap model){
        user.setName("Pavel");
        user.setSname("Petrashov");
        user.setSname("Petrashov");
        user.setAge(24);

        model.addAttribute("user",user);
        return "user"; 
    }
```

Then just use Expression language in jsp like @Ascalonian Suggested

```
${user.name}
${user.age}
```

Comment: what you need! thank you! I just could not figure out how to do it
${user.name}
${user.age}

Comment: @PavelPetrashov , Unable to understood what you want to say in comment , Can you please elaborate

Answer (score 1):

Add `ModelMap model` as a parameter in your `printUser`, then do `model.addAttribute("user", user);`

Then in your JSP, you just do: `${user.name}` like `<h1>${user.name}</h1>`

Comment: aaa understood. but as it then get in JSP?

Comment: @PavelPetrashov - Sorry,I don't know what you mean by *then drag in JSP*

Comment: <h1>getUser().name </h1>

Comment: @PavelPetrashov -  Use the code I mentioned in answer: `${user.name}`. I updated the answer to show exactly how to do it :-)